# Is there a way to check how many consecutive days I've gotten the Daily Bonus?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know that if you spin a Pokestop or catch a Pokemon every day for 7 days straight, you get a huge bonus of Stardust and Experience.

Is there a way to see how many days in a row I have currently accomplished either of these?

I know that it tells you this when you spin your first Pokestop or catch your first Pokemon on a given day, but is there a way to check your progress at any given point in time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from today (26th of March 2020, version 0.171.0 on Android), you can see where you are in your streak, and if  you did it for today. A filled golden circle means you have done it, an open golden circle indicates that you still need to do it, to continue your streak!

[image: Twitter picture from Pokemon Go]

Answer (score 6):

No.

On Android version 0.45.0 and iOS version 1.15.0, there is no other way to check your progress than spinning the first pokestop of the day, or catching the first pokemon of the day.

Comment: On 0.47.1 don't seem to have upgrade for this